# a question regarding quadratic forms in Korean Math Olympiad

Tags: inequality, contest-math

First of all, here is the question given in the Korean Junior Math Olympiad 2015:

Reals $a,b,c,x,y$ satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2=x^2+y^2=1$. Find the maximum value of$$(ax+by)^2+(bx+cy)^2$$

In his post over hear: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1158074p5501289

seoneo says: $(ax+by)^2+(bx+cy)^2$ is a quadratic form of the vector $(a,b,c)$ whose characteristic eq has the eigenvalues are $0$, $1-xy$, $1+xy$. Therefore, the maximum is that of $1+xy$, $1-xy$. Since the absolute value of $xy$ is bounded by $1/2$, we have the maximum $3/2$ where the equality occurs only when $xy= \pm 1/2$ where the existence of appropriate values of $a,b,c$ s are guaranteed.

Can someone explain how he got the the characteristic equation of $(a,b,c)$ ?

Comment: You can expand it as $a^2x^2+2abxy+b^2(x^2 + by^2)+2bcxy+c^2y^2$. So, the matrix of the quadratic form is $\begin{pmatrix}x^2&xy&0\\xy&(x^2+y^2)&xy\\0&xy&y^2\end{pmatrix}$. Compute its [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial).